# Using free public account of ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, license, story-map

I want to create a free public ArcGIS account to create some story maps.
Afterwards i want to share/publish this storymaps on my website. This website is off a travel agency.

Is it legal to use this self created story maps by a free public account on this website?

Because this story maps gives some images about a city, persons are interesting to visit this city because of the story map, so the travel agency gains some money due this story maps...

And if it's not possible.
Where can i find a license just to create story maps for a commercial way? Not for some other software.

Or is it possible to download the apps of the story maps and upload them on my website. Is it then still illegal?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question, and licensing questions are best asked of the vendor direct - see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5):

From https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#anchor6

> Can I use ArcGIS Online for free?
>
> > Yes. With a free public account you can create, store, and manage maps, apps, and files, and share them with others. You also get access to content shared by Esri and GIS users around the world. **Public accounts are for noncommercial use only.**

So no, I believe you'd be in violation of the terms of service.

Comment: Owkey

Where can i buy a license just to use the templates of the story maps in a commercial way?

Comment: I suspect you'll need an ArcGIS Online Organizational account. Pricing is available [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/purchase)

Comment: Also, if you already have ArcGIS Desktop licenses and pay for maintenance on those licenses, you're entitled to an ArcGIS Online account already. See [here](http://www.esri.com/software/maintenance/benefits/agol-entitlements) for more info.

Comment: I had last year a student license. To maintenance this license the price is to high...
Thanks for the website, i saw the price is flexibel. Do you have any idea how much it would be for a little organisation (travel agency)?

Comment: Hmm, I did not see that the price was flexible. There are a few buckets based on number of named users. Going the Organizational Account way, I think you're lowest cost is $2,500. You could purchase a standalone ArcGIS Desktop Basic license for $1,500, which would give you one named user in ArcGIS Online. The Desktop Basic route is probably your best (legal) bet.

Comment: Looks very expensive.... Thx for the information!

Comment: Those might be US numbers. If you're outside the US, they're almost certainly higher. (I work at Esri, but don't know the licensing/costs details)